# How do I resolve the type conversion error in below scenario

Tags: c#, implicit-conversion

I am going through basics of C# and .NET programming. I have a for loop as shown below.

```
for(var i = minHour; i <= maxHour; i++)
```

When i replace the above as:

```
for(var i = minHour; i <= maxHour; i+=0.5)
```

then i see an error as:

> Cannot implicitly convert type double to int.

I do not want to declare `i` as of type `double`, please help. I do not know anything about implicit conversion.

Can someone please help me how do I correct this,thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't increment an integer by `0.5`.  An integer can only represent whole numbers.  *Why* don't you want `i` declared as a floating-point type?

Comment: You are asking how to increment an `integer` type by `0.5`. That now how integers work.

Comment: If you need a decimal point number, your primary choices are either `float` or `double`.

Comment: Or ... decimal?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I follow why you want to keep using `var` for this situation instead of simply defining `double i =` which would solve your problem, but because you specified it in your question, I will ignore that for now.

Instead, let's take a look at why it is throwing this error in the first place. You are using `var i =` to define your variable, which you might think simply puts `i` into a generic variable. This isn't accurate in C#. Instead, C# will attempt to infer the type of this variable and because you are using `var i = minHour` the type of `i` is being inferred by the type of `minHour`.

You have a few options to fix this issue:

1. You can change `minHour` to be a double, which will solve this problem.
2. You can cast `minHour` as a double like so: `var i = (double)minHour`
3. You can do what you probably should and specify it when you declare `i` as so: `double i = minHour`

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it like this:

```
//beware when using i as indexer.
for(var i = minHour * 2; i <= maxHour * 2; i++)
//note: both minHour and maxHour need to be multiplied by 2
//Proof:
// n = maxHour - minHour =>
// 2 n = 2 (maxHour - minHour) =>
// (maxHour - minHour) * 2 = 2 * maxHour - 2 * minHour
//
```

Or, alternatively:

```
//type changed to double:
double minHour = 0, maxHour = 1;
for(var i = minHour; i <= maxHour; i+=0.5)
```

Or better (but not your favorite);

```
for(double i = minHour; i <= maxHour; i+=0.5)
```

Comment: or `float` instead of `double`.

Comment: Ah, yes, missed the part about the `I do not want to declare i as of type double`, makes me wonder if OP would like `float`.

Comment: Decimal is also available, see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tour-of-csharp/types-and-variables)

Comment: ... perhaps even `byte`s ;-)

Answer (score 0):

In the two examples, the variable `i` is being initialized to `minHour`. The compiler will infer the type from that statement alone, not any other usage. Presumably `minHour` is an `int`, so in both examples `i` is an `int`. Since it is an `int` the error message should now make more sense.

Note that `var` isn't some kind of dynamic type, which I suspect is the source of your misunderstanding. It is a known, fixed typed whose type is decided at compile time from its usage. So in both examples they are the equivalent of having the word `var` replaced by `int`. If you explicitly declare it as a `double` it will do what you want.

Tip: if you want to know what type the `var` will be, hover over it with the mouse.